# i have loaded a csv file in weka tool but J48 is not highlight

Tags: weka, decision-tree, j48

i upload a csv file in weka tool. After preprocessing, i want to apply J48 classifier but J48 is not highlighted there.

i want to apply decision tree classifier but it is not highlighted

Answer (score 1):

Each algorithm in Weka can only handle certain types of data (input attributes, class attribute, missong values etc), which define its *capabilities*. If these capabilities do not match the data, then the algorithm cannot be applied.

Check J48's capabilities (open its properties in the GenericObjectEditor and click on Capabilities) and check these against your dataset.

I would check whether your dataset has a numeric class atrribute and maybe string attributes.

Comment: it is a numeric class attribute

Comment: That's your problem then, as J48 is a classification algorithm, not a regression one. If the numeric attribute values represent actual categorical values, you could use the unsupervised NumericToNominal filter to convert it (you need to unser the class attribute in the preprocess panel before applying the filter).